# Ansible when conditional didn't work

Tags: ansible

i have some problems with my when conditional on my playbook:

here is the statement and I have no idea what is wrong.

main.yml

```
  - include: setup-ubuntu-trusty.yml
when: (ansible_distribution == "Ubuntu" and ansible_distribution_release == "trusty")

  - include: setup-ubuntu-xenial.yml
when: (ansible_distribution == "Ubuntu" and ansible_distribution_release == "xenial")
```

when i ran this script it gives me this error

```
    TASK: [utilities/requirements | requirements | include os-specific variables] *** 
skipping: [ansible-test-vm02]

TASK: [utilities/requirements | requirements | install] *********************** 
fatal: [ansible-test-vm02] => with_items expects a list or a set

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

I'm using Ubuntu xenial and the value of the two variables (ansible_distribution = Ubuntu / ansible_distribution_release = xenial)

I don't know why i jumps into the first file and give me the error. It should skip this and go into the xenial file.

Add:
This is the include file

setup-ubuntu-trusty.yml / setup-ubuntu-xenial.yml

```
- name: requirements | include os-specific variables
    include_vars: "{{ ansible_distribution | lower }}-{{ ansible_distribution_release | lower }}.yml"

  - name: requirements | install
    apt: name={{ item }} state=present
    with_items: "{{ package }}"
    register: out_download

  - name: requirements | output install
    debug: var=out_download
```

Comment: First, could you please properly indent your code samples to make sure that indentation is not an issue. Then, please debug the output of your variables in the `when` statement.

Comment: did it. and changed it to:
when: ({{ ansible_distribution }} == Ubuntu and {{ ansible_distribution_release }} == trusty)

now i got:  error while evaluating conditional: (Ubuntu == Ubuntu and xenial == trusty)

Comment: Do not use {{ }} in when conditions. I think you should give a bit more info about what the included playbooks are doing. Which one gets included? The problem doesn't seem to be in the include itself, but in the included playbook.

Comment: - name: requirements | include os-specific variables
    include_vars: "{{ ansible_distribution | lower }}-{{ ansible_distribution_release | lower }}.yml"

  - name: requirements | install
    apt: name={{ item }} state=present
    with_items: "{{ package }}"
    register: out_download

  - name: requirements | output install
    debug: var=out_download  
this is what the include does. it is the same as for xenial. just the variables are a bit different

Comment: i've added the first post

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this one:

```
- include: setup-ubuntu-trusty.yml
  when: ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu' and ansible_distribution_release == 'trusty'

- include: setup-ubuntu-xenial.yml
  when: ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu' and ansible_distribution_release == 'xenial'
```